# Clearing activities on stack not working

Tags: android

I'm having a difficulty clearing my activities on stack from a fragment. This is what I've done so far, I have 3 activities, namely: login, main, and profile. The first activity is the login. If successful, the app will go to main activity. Inside main activity, I have a button which goes to profile activity.

**LogoutAlertDialog.class**

```
   @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  OnClickListener positiveClick = new OnClickListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    

       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), 
                "Logging out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



       Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
       startActivity(i);
                getActivity().finish();


   }
  };

  OnClickListener negativeClick = new OnClickListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


   }
  };

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
  builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
  builder.setNegativeButton("No", negativeClick);
  builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", positiveClick);
  builder.setIcon(R.drawable.logout);
  builder.setTitle("Logout");
  Dialog dialog = builder.create();
  return dialog;
 }
```

**Profile.class:**

```
/**
 * On selecting action bar icons
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_logout:
        edit = shared.edit();

        edit.putString("Username", "");
        edit.putString("isLoggedIn", "no");
        edit.commit();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        LogoutAlertDialog alert = new LogoutAlertDialog();
        alert.show(fm, "");



        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But when I tried this, the app went to my Login.class - Activity but when I clicked the back button, it was going back to the main activity.

Does anybody know what's wrong with my code? Any help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I have set this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.sample.Profile"
        android:label="@string/myprofile"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.sample.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in my AndroidManifest because I'm using an ActionBar which lets user go back to its parent activity. Is there an issue with that?

Comment: one fix call `getActivity().finish();` after starting `Login` Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I tried doing that, still the same

Comment: just delete the addflag line..then after startactivity call finish() ..

Comment: @RanjitPati that doesn't work because I have the mainactivity is on stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: I still have the same issue

Comment: Why you need a FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
Creating a new task is not needed